# Cross domain AJAX getting the response, but in the error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make a cross-domain ajax request with `?t=bla` for the server and get the following response if success:

```
{"success":"yeeee","blaOne":"blabla","blaTwo":"blablabla"}
```

Same goes for the error, just instead of `yeeee`, it's `boooo`.

Success will be if the `?t=bla` and fail if the `?t=hm`

I did something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://...",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {t:'bla'},
  dataType: "jsonp"
}).then(function(response){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
})
```

As a result, I'm getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`, but I am able to see the response on a browser's resource file with the `yeeee` message! And it's the one of the `.catch(function(error)`. If I change the `data: {t:'hm'}` - I'm getting the appropriate(`boooo`) message, but again, it's the  `.catch(function(error)`.

Any ideas why is this happens and what I can do about it?

I don't have access to the server.

If there's no way to deal with this and it's a server's issue, how in this case I can access the resulted messages(can I at all?)

UPDATE:

I'm getting the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource is I use JSON instead of JSONP... The status I am getting is 200

Comment: You are specifying `dataType: 'jsonp'` yet the response is actually JSON, and they are not directly interchangeable. Set `dataType: 'json'` instead. If you made this change in an attempt to get around a CORS error, then that's an entirely separate issue which cannot be solved in JS alone.

Comment: @JaromandaX nope, I don't have the `console.log` output at all... All I'm getting is the file on the server with a response (`{"ggg":"ggg"...}`) on the sources tab in chrome

Comment: of course, and if you do set `dataType: 'json'` the server will have to allow CORS

Comment: The status returned is not 200 or 201. Can you log "response.status" or "error.status" ?

Comment: Also jsonp is not the format you described above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm getting the the `Content-Type` error message header from the server...

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error message

Comment: @ruhuves - why are you setting `dataType: "jsonp"` if the server **doesn't send you JSONP**

Comment: I'm getting the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` is I use `JSON` instead of `JSONP`... The status I am getting is `200`.

Comment: correct, but you can't "get around CORS" ... CORS is something the server does to stop people borrowing resources

Comment: That's what I expected. You *have* to use `dataType: 'json'` here as that's what the server returns, however as you're making a cross-domain request you're bound by the SOP. Hence as the server does not return valid CORS headers for the domain you're calling from you will be blocked from dealing with the response in JS (although you will see a valid response in the console)...

Comment: You will need to proxy the request on your local server and have the JS call that instead. Alternatively get in touch with the owners of the domain you're calling and ask them to add CORS headers to the endpoint(s) you call, although that's highly unlikely to happen. See the duplicate I marked for more information

Comment: @JaromandaX So it's a server's "problem" and there's no workaround on this? I just want to be sure I'm getting it currently. And if indeed it is so, why am I still able to see the message? doesn't it should be blocked or something?

Comment: It's not a 'problem' it's a security feature to stop unauthorised stealing of content and phishing attempts.

Comment: no, it's *your* problem, you want there resources, and they don't want you having them -as far as what's in the browser console, that's useful information for code developers ... they can see what they are doing is right, just that the server doesn't want them doing it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But if I use JSON, I don't get any message in the console with the response at all... If I use JSONP - I do. what am I not getting here, please?

Comment: As I've mentioned in several comments now, the console will always show the response. The browser will block you from accessing the data in JS due to the SOP. There is absolutely nothing you can do about this in JS as it's a security feature of the browser.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Got it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!